# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Blank Screen with cursor

Tags: boot

I started up after updating, I am met with a Ubuntu logo and such and then a blank screen pops up and all I am left with is a cursor, I use Alt + f5 and I get a log in screen and I type my username how I guess it would be and then the password option pops up and it doesn’t let me type anything and when I press enter it says log in fail.